# Sending var with load jquery

Tags: jquery

I don't know why doesn't work:

```
function Client(wuku) {
    $("#show").load('source.php #showclientapp?weke=' + wuku);
};
```

I want to know how I can make this part `?weke='+wuku` work with  `#showclientapp`. I want to send the variable `wuku` to `source.php #showclientapp`.

Any answer would be really helpful.

Comment: Well, the space probably isn't helpling you

Comment: The space is not making the difference in this case, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: PHP wouldnt consider anything after the # as the URI, you can use JavaScript or modify the uri source.php/showclientapp?weke=

Comment: It still load all the source.php, i just want the #showclientapp x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The querystring should be provided to the PHP file not the selector, like this:

```
function Client(wuku) {
    $("#show").load('source.php?weke=' + wuku + ' #showclientapp');
};
```

Comment: It seems to load all the file source.php. I just want to load the #showclientapp in my file. I don't know why it doesn't, it should be okay.

Comment: Are you sure that element exists in the page when it's requested?

Comment: Yes, I have a form in source.php #showclientapp where i click in search button and then send me to a new load list where i can select one user and when i click in the desired user i want to execute then Client function and i want to sent to my form this user information selected.